# How to conditionally include a script reference in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a ASP.NET MVC web application that is very dynamic in it's nature:

A controller loads data from some service. Based on this response, it calls others sub-controller's actions which in turn may or may not render certain views. The response of the service is dependent upon a lot of factors and may change a lot of the page's output.

Now we're in a situation that only if a certain sub-view is rendered, we need to include a javascript bundle:

- If a certain sub-controller renders a certain sub-view, we must include the script reference.
- We must not include this bundle in the page when this certain sub-view ist not rendered.
- The availability of the sub-view is determined dynamically from some other sub-controllers remote call.
- The script absolutely needs to be included in the page header, since it executes certain code that will cause problems if done later (setting document.domain and stuff).

How can we achieve that in a clean and MVCy-way?

Comment: _"sub-controller [...] change a lot of the page's output [...] sub-view [...] clean and MVCy-way"_ - your question contradicts itself. ;-) You may however want to just put it in the `ViewBag`.

Comment: Would a `@RenderSection("headerScripts" required: false)` in your _Layout take care of that for you?

Comment: @Billdr Didn't thought of that, but that seems a good idea. Will check if that works in our environment.

Comment: @CodeCaster how would you build an extremely dynamic, user-changable CMS without dividing every reusable module in a separate subcontroller/partialview combination and have them combined from the user given data in a more MVCy way?

Comment: @Billdr It does not work. Due to the de-coupling of the seperate modules and layered sub-views, I come to a point where the systems tells me I could not call a view that uses RenderSection directly that needs to pass the section contents to the layout from its sub-views.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you mean by all those terms ('dynamic', 'module', 'subcontroller', 'sub-view') nor what functionality they offer so I'm not going to answer that (an alternative could for example be an AJAX-driven site that updates the page with HTML rendered from partial views, but it really depends on everything your application tries to offer), but you might want to show what your code currently looks like, why you think that code is not 'MVCy' and what things exactly you would like to see improved to make it more 'clean'.

Comment: @CodeCaster the problem is that I have no working code to make more clean. I have not solved the task and I currently can't find a way to solve it. I have several views that can call several html helpers. Some of them load user-generated content blocks or web page modules and display them user RenderAction() calls.  Some of those need certain javascript files that need to be included in the <head>  tag, and that must not be included if the certain module is not available on the page. And it needs to place certain javascript functions at the end of the page.

Comment: Well like I said, try the `ViewBag`. When you say _"The availability of the sub-view is determined dynamically from some other sub-controllers remote call"_, then the result of that call can be used to set something like `ViewBag.IncludeMyMagicBundle = true`, and in the layout view (or wherever you want to do it), you put a `<script src="..."`  or `@Scripts.Render("~/my/magic/bundle")` when `ViewBag.IncludeMyMagicBundle` is not `null` but `true`.

Comment: @CodeCaster It seems that the layout has a different viewbag than the sub-controller. I can't pass any information from the subviews to the layout this way. I can pass the information around in HttpContext.Items though. It seems the views are all executed after the controller code.

Comment: It would really really help if you can show some rough outline of how your controllers and views interact (i.e. show some example controller, 'sub'controller, view and 'sub'view code), as from this description alone I can't figure out what your code looks like.

Comment: We have an entry controller. That loads the content from the cms backend. This data determines the used layout and what entry view will be displayed (there could be multiple). Then the view defines the main contents html structure (zones) and calls a HtmlHelper "RenderViewsInZone". This in turn determines the modules for this zone from the page contents and calls RenderAction(controller, action) for each module that the user configured for this zone on the page. This way we can implement new modules as for our CMS by simply adding controllers, actions and views.